# How to send little data between admin pages of my plugin?

Tags: plugins, admin, admin-menu

I have a plugin that creates two pages in admin menu:

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=list-records

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=add-edit-record
```

I'm regularly using add-edit-record to to **create** some sort of record and to put it in wp database. On the other hand page list-records **lists all the records** I already created plus allows me to **delete record**. I want to let add-edit-record also to **load** certain existing record from database and let me **edit it** (and save afterwards of course). But how can I call add-edit-record with information which record I want to open and work on?

My idea (maybe naive) is either save ID of edited record in some config option of wp-database and always check that item when opening add-edit-record page - which seems to me very complicated.
Or call add-edit-record page with certain data as a parameter, like

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=add-edit-record&edit-id=999
```

but here I have no idea how can I obtain this parameter in my add-edit-record page.

Maybe I'm thinking in completle wrong direction so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with your last idea - generate a URL like so:

```
$raw_url = admin_url( 'admin.php?page=add-edit-record&edit-id=' . $id );
$esc_url = esc_url( $raw_url ); // For href attributes and the like
```

And then in your handler for `add-edit-record`:

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['edit-id'] ) && $id = absint( $_GET['edit-id'] ) ) {
    if ( ! $record = get_record( $id ) )
        wp_die( 'Nope' ); // Or something similar
}
```

Comment: Excellent, it works! But in general, is this correct way how plugins should internally communicate? Doesn't violate it some rules of Wordpress?

Comment: Nope. It's standard procedure for almost any web-based server-side application to pass arguments between requests in URL parameters, including WP.